# Is it possible to send dynamic "Key" names for "Key: Value" pairs from Unity C# to Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:**

The current Firebase structure looks like this:

[image]

**Goal:**

From Unity C#, I want the "userID" piece to be dynamic based on a variable.

**Question:**

Is it possible to send dynamic Key names from Unity C# to Firebase Realtime Database?

**Code Example:**

```
public void CreateUser()
{

    userID = user.UserId; //this is the auth userID

    Username UserIDtoUsername = new Username(registerUsername.text, userID);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(UserIDtoUsername);
    dbReference.Child("usernames").SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);

}

public class Username
{
    public string username;
    public string userID;

    public Username(string username, string userID)
    {
        userID = username; //this does not work because we are not passing back the variables
        //need a way to pass back the user's current userID and username to then convert to Json and into Firebase
    }

}
```

Comment: `//this does not work ...` well first of all it doesn't work at all since you overwrite the parameter `userID` and do assign absolutely nothing to the field `public string userID` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can have a dynamic field inside a class. The names of the fields in a class are always predefined. This means that you cannot use an object of the class to get the desired behavior.

> Is it possible to send dynamic Key names from Unity C# to Firebase?

Yes, it's possible. If you need to have the actual UID as a key, then you should consider using the following line of code:

```
dbReference.Child("usernames").Child(userID).SetValueAsync(registerUsername.text);
```

Assigning the value of `username` to the `userID` in the class, will not provide the desired behavior. Will only set the value of `userID` to the `username` field.